# C# HttpClient handle swedish characters åäö in response

Tags: c#

When sending a test request in Burp I get correct values for åäö in Swedish but using HttpClient I only get this character: �

[image]

I have tried setting the `Accept-Language` header to `sv-SE` and `sv` but with the same result. I have also tried getting `GetByteArrayAsync` and converting this to UTF-8 but no luck there neither.

```
private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public HttpService()
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "sv");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
}

public string GetRequest(string url)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
    {
        //Same result
        //var byteArray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        //var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            var result = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

Headers from server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 31903
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: Sun, 14 May 2017 22:00:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Set-Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDCSACQTRA=<REMOVED>; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 15 May 2017 13:10:18 GMT
```

Comment: What encoding is the server using? (What do the headers look like?)

Comment: @JonSkeet See update for response headers

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: Have you tried setting charset in request `Accept-Charset: utf-8` or any similar?

Comment: You have to decode the bytes according to the charset used by the server. There should be a `charset` attribute on the [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). If you can modify the server, follow [How to: Select an Encoding for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx). If not, try to guess the encoding by looking at the hex of the problem characters in the response. It *should* be `ISO-8859-1`

Comment: Hmm. `application/json` *should* use UTF-8 as per RFC 7159. Presumably it's not. Can you use the hex view to find the exact bytes being used to represent the data? (And do you know who's running the server, so you can ask them to fix it?)

Comment: From your print it's clear is a client problem. On postman (Google's Chrome Extension) you can se headers send from the client and the servers returns. Try simulate this issue on postman and then fix your code with the correct header;

Comment: @m.rogalski Yes it did not fix the problem

Comment: @RemusRusanu Thank you very much, this solved it!

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I thought it was very weird as well, never had this problem before. However using encoding ISO-8859-1 solved the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ogglas answer will fix it for åäö but might not work for ÅÄÖ. ISO-8859-1 correspondes to either
- Windows-1252 Western European (Windows). Code page 1252
or
- iso-8859-1    Western European (ISO). Code page 28591

To be sure to get the correct encoding, you might want to use `Encoding.GetEncoding(int codePage)` instead. For more information about different encoding see, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.8

Here is an example code where the response string is ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö0123456789!"#¤%&/()=?^*_:;>@£${[]}\~|<,.-¨'´+

```
using System.Net.Http;
using log4net;
using System.Text;

namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public static class Enc {

        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Enc));

        public static string GetRequest(HttpClient client, string url, int codepage) {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result) {
                var byteArray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                var result = Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage).GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static void Example(HttpClient client, string url) {
            string result1 = GetRequest(client, url, 1252);
            string result2 = GetRequest(client, url, 28591);
            log.Debug(result1);
            log.Debug(result2);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÅÄÖabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö0123456789!"#¤%&/()=?^*_:;>@£${[]}\~|<,.-¨'´+"
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÿÿÿabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzåäö0123456789!"#¤%&/()=?^*_:;>@£${[]}\~|<,.-¨'´+
```

where ÿ shows up as a black character xC3? in my logs.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @RemusRusanu. Working code:

```
public string GetRequest(string url)
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result)
    {
        var byteArray = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
        var result = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        return result;
    }
}
```